# Multi-Threaded SQLite Crash

Tags: c++, multithreading, sqlite

I'm trying to use SQLite 3.7.5 in a multi-threaded C++ program. I've narrowed it down to a few simple lines of code:

```
sqlite3 *Database;
sqlite3_stmt *Stmt;

int retval=sqlite3_open("database.db3",&Database);
retVal=sqlite3_prepare(&Database,"CREATE TABLE RawData (Key CHAR(5))",-1,&Stmt,0);
retval=sqlite3_step(Stmt);
retval=sqlite3_finalize(Stmt);
```

When I call this code directly from my main process, it works fine. However, if I use CreateThread() to create a thread:

```
unsigned long ThreadId;
CreateThread(0,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) InserterThread,&Info,0,&ThreadId);
```

I get a "buffer overrun" Visual Studio message on the **sqlite3_step** call. If I debug, I see the crash location is in _CRT_DEBUGGER_HOOK in dbghook.c.

I'm using the Multi-threaded Static VC libraries, and am compiling with the defines:

```
SQLITE_THREADSAFE=2
THREADSAFE=2
```

I have verified with **sqlite3_threadsafe()**.

I can trace a bit into the SQLite 3 code, but I'm hoping some one will spot an obvious problem with my code and save me the aggrevation.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, please post an answer with the solution for others.

Comment: I never got to the real cause of the problem. I think I ended up reducing the project to a minimum, and the problem went away. I then gradually added components figuring I'd eventually find the one that triggered the problem, but I managed to add all components without the problem resurfacing. So it's a mystery...

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the SQLITE_THREADSAFE define is for compiling, they don't force the library into the behavior, just make it available.

You still have to tell sqlite that you want multi-threaded behavior, either when you start up the database or during runtime.

> Start-time selection of threading mode
>
> Assuming that the compile-time threading mode is not single-thread,
>   then the threading mode can be changed during initialization using the
>   sqlite3_config() interface. The SQLITE_CONFIG_SINGLETHREAD verb puts
>   SQLite into single-thread mode, the SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD verb
>   sets multi-thread mode, and the SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED verb sets
>   serialized mode.
>
> Run-time selection of threading mode
>
> If single-thread mode has not been selected at compile-time or
>   start-time, then individual database connections can be created as
>   either multi-thread or serialized. It is not possible to downgrade an
>   individual database connection to single-thread mode. Nor is it
>   possible to escalate an individual database connection if the
>   compile-time or start-time mode is single-thread.
>
> The threading mode for an individual database connection is determined
>   by flags given as the third argument to sqlite3_open_v2(). The
>   SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX flag causes the database connection to be in the
>   multi-thread mode and the SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX flag causes the
>   connection to be in serialized mode. If neither flag is specified or
>   if sqlite3_open() or sqlite3_open16() are used instead of
>   sqlite3_open_v2(), then the default mode determined by the
>   compile-time and start-time settings is used.

Referenced from http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

Comment: No luck. I tried sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD); and also using sqlite3_open_v2 with SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX. Same problem.

Comment: I've since coded a standalone version of the problem and am not seeing the problem. This is a rather large project, I'm going to have to gradually add components until the problem resurfaces.  Thanks anyway.